# Mouse and Keyboard hangs

Tags: 18.04

From time to time mouse and keyboard stop working for ~1s.

If I typed when getting this problem the key gets printed like 20 times after unfreezing.

If I used the mouse the action during this time is ignored.

It's an old Dell Latitude (E6530) but with a new SSD.

I tested the cpu and no error was reported.
I tested the ram with memtest 4.3.7 - no error. 
I also tested it with memtest 5.01 singlecore - no error, if I however force multi-threading on startup it hangs at test #7, pass 21%, test 81% but reports no error.

If it were a ram issue there should be more than just a 1s freeze I guess...

Help appreciated :-)

Comment: You can run `htop` in terminal and sort by cpu usage to see if there is a process that has spike in usage when that happens. There are also other monitoring tools like `glances` which provide even more info (i/o, network).

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz There is no spike. Any chance that there is an issue with the installation? How could I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the kern.log in /var/log and found this error "ACPI: _DB_.PCI0.PEG0.VID_: failed to evaluate _DSM"

The issue seems to be related to gnome somehow: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=137096

I replaced it with kde and now the error is gone except on startup (where I don't care about it).